# how to redeclare core model attribute type without extending it in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

By default Hybtis gives CreditCardType as a mandatory attribute. I want to make it Optional by using `redeclare=true` (without extending it with new model). I am wondering why its not updating `CreditCardPaymentInfo` model. I am doing like this

```
<itemtype code="CreditCardPaymentInfo" autocreate="false" generate="false" >
        <attributes>
            <attribute qualifier="type" type="CreditCardType" redeclare="true" autocreate="false" generate="true">
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true" />
                <persistence type="property"/>
            </attribute>
       </attributes>        
    </itemtype>
```

My ant build is working fine. But whenever i m updating running system, Hybris is not making this attribute non mandatory.

In case if I am extending it with my custom model and re-declaring it then its working, but that's what i don't need. I just want to make it optional without extending it.

I think its possible with Impex also, but i don't know the way. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't redeclare an attribute without extending a type.
The documentation for redeclare says it clearly:

> Lets you re-define the attribute definition from an inherited type. In
>   essence, you can use a different type of attribute as well as
>   different modifier combinations than on the supertype.

Impex to the rescue. You can alter attribute modifiers with an impex afterwards.
Place following impex script

```
update AttributeDescriptor;enclosingType(code)[unique=true];qualifier[unique=true];optional
;CreditCardPaymentInfo;type;true
```

under `<your-extension>/resources/impex/essentialdata-<chosse-a-name>.impex`.

On each typesystem update (or initialize) this impex gets executed and marks `CreditCardPaymentInfo.type` as optional. For testing purpose, you can run this script within `hac`, too.

Comment: That exactly i want. Thanks for this :)

Comment: this doesnt work on making an attribute encrypted ( modifier encrypted = true). Any additional steps required for making an existing attribute encrypted?